# Firebase Authentication Unit Testing via emulators with Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I've been trying to unit test every testable piece of code in my projects and I recently found that Firebase has added Authentication as part of their emulation suite. I'm working on an Angular/Nativescript project right now and I'm running my database tests with the Firestore emulator as a part of my testing environment and I love it. Thing is, a bit of finagling is required to get this to work in the first place.

Basically I just configure `TestBed` with both the required Firebase modules and provide a `SETTINGS` object which tells `AngularFirestoreModule` to target the emulator instead of my production database. It looks something like this:

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports:[
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFirestoreModule
    ],
    providers: [
        //this is what I'm unit testing
        { provide: Database, useClass: FirebaseDatabase },
        //this is the object I provide to my testing environment
        { provide: SETTINGS, useValue: { host: 'localhost:8080', ssl: false } }  
    ]
});
```

So far so good. Problem is when I try to apply that same concept to Authentication. Going through the [AngularFireAuth](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts) source code it seems like it requires injection for the mostly the same stuff as the [AngularFirestore](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/firestore/firestore.ts) module except `SETTINGS`. What do I need to provide in `TestBed` to target the Authentication emulator?